# How to avoid common words such as "the" when displaying results alphabetically from select statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I've currently got a select statement below.

`$sql="SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE '$letter%' ORDER BY title ASC";`

Whenever someone visits view.php?letter=m, it displays all movies starting with that letter in alphabetical order but if there is a movie such as "The Man Without a Face", this will be displayed with the T's instead of the M's because of the word "the". I would like it to ignore the word "The" so it displays with the movies starting with M but when it shows with other movies starting with M, I would still like it to display with "The" at the start of it.

How would I got about achieving this?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still want to be able to use an index access path for the sorting, so the best way is to create a column `sort_title` that contains a normalized version of `title`. Every time you update the record, you also update that derived column accordingly.

Ideally, you also use that `sort_title` column to filter against (so that a single, more compact index can be used), but this may be a bit tricky.

Comment: This is probably the easiest way around this problem for me. I almost feel stupid for not thinking of it myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace()`:

```
order by replace(lower(title, 'the ', ''))
```

Perhaps a more generic answer uses regular expressions:

```
order by (case when lower(title) regexp '^(the |a |an ).*'
               then substr(title, instr(title, ' ') + 1)
               else title
          end)
```

Comment: If your database supports derived columns or functional indices that would be a good scenario for them.

Comment: @Thilo . . . I was guessing MySQL, but I might be wrong.